# weird behavior when loop for 40000 times

Tags: java

```
private static void loop( Supplier<CompletionStage<Boolean>> body) {
    CompletionStage<Boolean> result = body.get();
    Log.i(TAG,"after get");
    result.whenComplete((r, e) -> {
         if (r) {
            Log.i(TAG,"call loop ");
            loop( body);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG,"exit loop");
        }
    });
}

int cnt = 0;

void test() {
    CompletableFuture<Void> supervisor = new CompletableFuture<>();
    loop(() -> {
        Log.i(TAG,"cnt="+cnt);
        if(cnt ++ < 40000)
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(true);
        else  {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(false);
        }
    });
    Log.i(TAG,"leave");
}
```

Output:

I/MainActivity: cnt=0
I/MainActivity: after get
I/MainActivity: call loop
I/MainActivity: cnt=1
I/MainActivity: after get
I/MainActivity: call loop

...

I/MainActivity: cnt=3073
I/MainActivity: after get
I/MainActivity: call loop
I/MainActivity: cnt=3074
I/MainActivity: after get
I/MainActivity: call loop
I/MainActivity: cnt=3075
I/MainActivity: after get
I/MainActivity: leave

Expect the loop will end after 40000 times, but it only run around 300~4000 times then loop ends.

Comment: My guess: a `StackOverflowError` occurs and you don't see it. Try to catch it (or any Throwable) in your `whenComplete`-callback and log it, just for debugging. If this is the problem, you should probably refactor your code to avoid such deep recursion.

Comment: Not any exception thrown during the test, that's why it is weird, you can try run above android code to see if result is different.

Comment: I/art: ```Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<...>: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB           
at void <package name>.MainActivity.loop(java.util.function.Supplier) (MainActivity.java:32)```

Comment: @lucas: Note that you cannot directly log when such an error occurs because the stack is already full. I've copied your code, removed unknown references (like `Log` and `TAG`), wrapped the `loop(body)` call in a `try { ... } catch (Throwable t} { error = t; }` where `error` is a static field which I output at the end of the program. And indeed it's filled with a `StackOverflowError`. Result is here: https://www.online-java.com/dwEnACmPax

Comment: Interesting, I run the code in android studio, no Exception or StackOverflowError can be caught. And If there's any exception thrown but not caught, the log "I/MainActivity: leave" shouldn't be seen?

Comment: @HeroWanders If you run the code in a standard java project with eclipse , still you won't get any exception or error. I know this issue must relates to stack overflow but curious of the behavior.

Comment: I've created a Main.java file (contents as in the link to the online-java project) and started it directly with `java Main.java` via CLI and I can also see the same `StackOverflowError` there: https://i.postimg.cc/8k9bTTRM/cli.png  -- I've even downloaded Eclipse, added the file to a fresh project with Java 19 and started it there, same error: https://i.postimg.cc/9079JZqF/eclipse.png -- only difference is what part of the stack trace is printed, which probably depends on the JVM start parameters (max stack size `-Xss`)

Comment: Maybe due to java version problem? Below is run from command line?

D:\code\eclipse-workspace\test1\com\test>java  test.java
after get. call loop cnt=1351
after get. call loop cnt=1352
after get. call loop cnt=1353
after get. call loop
leave

D:\code\eclipse-workspace\test1\com\test>java --version
java 11.0.17 2022-10-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.17+10-LTS-269)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.17+10-LTS-269, mixed mode)